# why does this log out both if console.log(x) is logging out?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting both of these outputs but I don't know why

```
var sample = (x) =>  console.log(x) || x.slice(1); 
console.log(sample('jeff'));
// why does this log out both if console.log(x) is logging out?
// jeff
// eff
```

Comment: `console.log` returns `undefined`. Since that is a falsy value, you also get the right-hand side of the OR.

Comment: You're logging `x` and the return of `sample`.

Comment: Why would you expect *not* to see both `console.log()` outputs?

Comment: are you saying console.log is falsy by default?
aren't we plugging 'jeff' as x?@VLAZ

Comment: The `console.log()` function returns `undefined` no matter what parameters you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`undefined` above is the return value of `console.log()`. This means that

```
console.log(...) || 'here?'
```

will always execute the second statement, where

```
console.log(...) && 'here?'
```

will not ever. This has caught me a few times. `:\`

Think of it like this (pseudocode):

```
function log(...arguments): void {
    for (argument of arguments)
        print argument

    // What do you return?
}
```

Comment: is it because the console.log itself is seen as a falsey value?

Comment: Yes. Console log never return true to get short circuited there .

Comment: Pointy's comment above suggests the truth: There is not really a valid response to invoking `console.log()`; it prints what you pass it to somewhere else, returning `true` or really anything would be strange. Hence, it's return is "voided", e.g. `undefined` (which is falsey).

Comment: following that logic why would anything print at all in the && example above?

this one => console.log(...) && 'here?'

Comment: @ErikDeLuna Because Javascript returns the value of the last truthy expression in a sequence. Try `console.log(true && false)`.

Comment: that makes sense @JaredFarrish
i just though the && meant they both had to be true for it to print both

Comment: @ErikDeLuna PHP for instance would evaluate `1 && 2` as truthy true/false; if you `var_dump(1 && 2)` you will always get `true`. Javascript would evaluate that as `2`. It returns the last truthy value, `||` allows further checking until truthy, `&&` will also pass the decision to the last evaluation. This is useful in functional programming.

Comment: regarless it will always return the last truthy value

Comment: @ErikDeLuna [Yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Answer (score 1):

To explain what is going on in your function, when you pass the value 'jeff' to your function call it evaluates the expression `console.log(x) || x.slice(1)`, which first logs `"jeff"` and since `console.log()` returns `undefined`, `x.slice()` is executed which returns `"eff"`. And because you have wrapped the you function call in another `console.log()` it finally logs the returned value "eff" to the console.

Hence logging two values to the console.

To clarify try executing this in console using dev tools in your browser

```
 console.log("hello") || console.log("hey")

 // expected result two logs in console "hello" and "hey"
```

now try executing this in the console

```
 console.log("hello") && console.log("hey")

 // expected result only one log in console "hello"
```

In the second case this happens because first `console.log` gets called which logs "hello" to the console and returns `undefined` and because undefined is falsy the 2nd `console.log` never gets called.